# Substituting the value with spaces for a variable in bash script - the correct way

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, string

I have a compilation script that can compile the program with and without the debug symbols.

I want to ask via bash prompt ( `read` ) the user to choose whether he wants a debug version or not with something like this:

```
compiler_options_for_debug_version=''
debug_flag=''
if [[ "$debug_switch" == "Y" ]]; then
    compiler_options_for_debug_version=("CFLAGS=\"-g -O0\"")
    debug_flag='--with-debug'
fi
```

but the `CFLAGS="-g -O0"` is giving me some headache as it gives an error:

```
vagrant@node02:~$ compiler_options_for_debug_version=("CFLAGS=\"-g -O0\""); $compiler_options_for_debug_version;
CFLAGS="-g: command not found
```

I have tried:

```
compiler_options_for_debug_version=("CFLAGS=\"-g -O0\"")
compiler_options_for_debug_version="CFLAGS=\"-g -O0\""
compiler_options_for_debug_version='CFLAGS="-g -O0"'
```

I expect this `CFLAGS="-g -O0"` exact thing in here:

```
$compiler_options_for_debug_version ./configure --with-luajit --with-http_postgres_module ...
```

so it should be expanded to:

```
CFLAGS="-g -O0" ./configure --with-luajit --with-http_postgres_module ...
```

As a last resort I could just add an `if [ ... ]` statment and hardcode the `CFLAGS="-g -O0"` but it should be possible to do it the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the value in a variable

```
compiler_options_for_debug_version=""
if something; then
    compiler_options_for_debug_version="-g -O0"
fi
```

Then make sure you quote the variable when you use it: this is just as important.

```
CFLAGS="$compiler_options_for_debug_version" ./configure ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if `CFLAGS=""` ??

Comment: Ok, I was that this can be safelly done. Here is a ref: http://aggregate.org/rfisher/Tutorials/Make/make5.html